# Giorgio - Script Font Identification

Tags: fonts, script

[image: Giorgio]

Can anyone help me find this script font? I have googled or use 4 or more font identfiers already, couldn't find, very **urgent**.

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - *Please* look through **[tour]** to get a sense of our community – who we are and what we’re about. *Then* look over **[ask]** and **[answer]** a question to see what makes a good query here, *and* how best to frame it. We have some requirements http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366 for font identification questions, please take a look and edit your question to meet those guidelines - thanks!

Comment: Although I believe the answer given is correct, a word of advice: you have done a good job of separating the letters in the script, but for identification sites/software to work there has to be sufficient separation for a bounding box around each character not to include any of the next. That is, there must be space for a vertical line between each character. In your image, every character overlaps its neighbours, and that will cause difficulty with automated recognition.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a font, the difference between the same characters is too small to be an alternative glyph design and too different to be the same character of a font.

Check the two "i" and "o".

[image]

The hardness of the stroke suggests that these are characters made manually, scanned, traced and mounted in a vector drawing program.